# How to query new Android Calendar App Reminders?

Tags: android, calendar, reminders

Last month Google Added the ability to add standalone Reminders into their Calendar app (see [article](http://lifehacker.com/you-can-now-add-reminders-to-google-calendar-1746655232)), i have tried to get those events through the standard Calendar Content provider but without any success, those items are not returned by the CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI query and also are not listed as alerts in the CalendarContract.CalendarAlerts.CONTENT_URI.

Maybe this data is not exported at all.

P.S. I know how to query reminders associated to events, this is not what i am asking here

Comment: Any updates on this one? Thanks.

Comment: @OferR, any updates?

Comment: Not possible yet afaik, will set a bounty